# why timeout not stop infinite loop

Tags: php, apache, timeout, infinite-loop

Why php or apache not stop infinite loop?

```
while (true)
{
    sleep(5);
}
```

Apache have default TimeOut = 300.
Php - max_execution_time = 30

But this loop can work over hour. Why?

Comment: You want that your Apache stop your `while` loop after the max time? Why would you want that?

Comment: don't timeout for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sleep() happens outside of your script, it doesn't contribute to the max execution time of your script.

> Note: The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), the sleep()
>   function, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the
>   maximum time that the script has been running.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php